# how to use same script.js file for calling different CSS class using multiple Ids

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've made a page where same donut chart will come 4 times. And there size will be same. But there position will be different. One should take atleast 20px space from another. For this, I've written 4 css style. But when i try to call them using same script.js they are not working but when i added a new script2.js with changing the id name it works. For this i had to make 4 script.js whose works is same.

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
myCanvas.width = 50;
myCanvas.height = 40;

var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawArc(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.stroke();
}
function drawPieSlice(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
var myVinyls = {
    "Positive": 50,
    "Negative": 10,
    "N/A": 20
};
var Piechart = function (options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.colors = options.colors;

    this.draw = function () {
        var total_value = 0;
        var color_index = 0;
        for (var categ in this.options.data) {
            var val = this.options.data[categ];
            total_value += val;
        }

        var start_angle = 0;
        for (categ in this.options.data) {
            val = this.options.data[categ];
            var slice_angle = 2 * Math.PI * val / total_value;

            drawPieSlice(
                this.ctx,
                this.canvas.width / 2,
                this.canvas.height / 2,
                Math.min(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2),
                start_angle,
                start_angle + slice_angle,
                this.colors[color_index % this.colors.length]
            );

            start_angle += slice_angle;
            color_index++;
        }

        //drawing a white circle over the chart
        //to create the doughnut chart
        if (this.options.doughnutHoleSize) {


            drawPieSlice(
                this.ctx,
                this.canvas.width / 2,
                this.canvas.height / 2,
                this.options.doughnutHoleSize * Math.min(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2),
                0,
                2 * Math.PI,
                "#206020"
            );
        }

    }
}
var myDougnutChart = new Piechart(
    {
        canvas: myCanvas,
        data: myVinyls,
        colors: ["#32CD32", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00"],
        doughnutHoleSize: 0.7
    }
);

myDougnutChart.draw();
```

This is the html and css

```
     //html//

<div class="chart2">
    <canvas id="myCanvas1"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</div>
<div class="chart3">
    <canvas id="myCanvas2"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>

</div>

     //CSS File//

.chart2 {
    padding: 1em 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 66;
    height: 63;
    position: absolute;
    left: 122px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.chart3 {
    padding: 1em 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 66;
    height: 63;
    position: absolute;
    left: 162px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

But i want only one script.js to call all the css file. But it's not working. I've to write separate JS file for calling separate css file.

Comment: It is not terribly clear what you are asking or attempting to accomplish. It is especially hard because you have not posted the javascript you are referring to. Please edit the question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @rmlan i've added the jS file

Comment: Try moving your script tag to the bottom of the HTML file (right inside the `body` tag).

Comment: @KevinBoucher I've tried that but still it's not working. Only one chart is showing up but other's aren't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly your problem is that you're drawing in a hardcoded canvas element. Parametrise your drawer and call it two times with different id. Change your script according to this pattern

```
function drawInCanvas(id){
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById(id);
  myCanvas.width = 50;
  myCanvas.height = 40;

  // and the rest of the code...
}

drawInCanvas("myCanvas1");
drawInCanvas("myCanvas2");
```