# apply same JavaScript code to several canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to apply some JavaScript to canvas, all canvas have the same height and width properties.
Since I'm a very beginner in JavaScript and I've never really manipulated canvas on HTML, is it possible to do that by simply using one JavaScript file ?

I've found another question that is really similar to my problem here : [how to use same script.js file for calling different CSS class using multiple Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533223/how-to-use-same-script-js-file-for-calling-different-css-class-using-multiple-id)

but even when i try the provided solution the code is even more broken as before.

Here is my HTML display for testing

```
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="color_chane">Button 1</a>
        <canvas id="dot_1"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="color_chane">Button 2</a>
        <canvas id="dot_2"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="color_chane">Button 3</a>
        <canvas id="dot_3"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and here is my JavaScript for those buttons, consider that this is the only JavaScript running on the page so no conflict between diferents scripts files.

```
/*Canvas Var*/
var nbCanvas = 3;

/*Dots variables*/
var nbDots = 20;
var weight = 60;
var net = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nbDots; i++) {
    var dot = new Dot();
    dot.setup();
    net.push(dot);
}

/* Colors var */
var index = localStorage.getItem('index') ? localStorage.getItem('index') : 0; /*save the value in the browser memory, if it already exists get it else set it to 0*/
var first = ["#4B2F73", "#8C0335", "#21EE03", "#011526", "#2960A4", "#0F0140", "#8C0444"];
var second = ["#3B2559", "#021E73", "#26C013", "#00070D", "#3E86C0", "#060126", "#591547"];
var third = ["#0A2B40", "#0442BF", "#29A619", "#024059", "#11C6D8", "#0D05F2", "#101C40"];
var fourth = ["#71C6D9", "#034C8C", "#737373", "#024959", "#BDA092", "#060273", "#011526"];
var fifth = ["#5FCDD9", "#023059", "#282828", "#3CA692", "#D83911", "#0ABF04", "#F20505"];

class Dot {
    x = 100;
    y = 100;
    radius = (canvas.width / canvas.height)/1.5;
    direction = 0;
    speed = 1;

    fillStyle(){
        index = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('index'));
        if (this.x > 4 * (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
            context.fillStyle = fifth[index];
        } else if (this.x > 3 * (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
            context.fillStyle = fourth[index];
        } else if (this.x > 2 * (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
            context.fillStyle = third[index];
        } else if (this.x > (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
            context.fillStyle = second[index];
        } else {
            context.fillStyle = first[index];
        }

    }
    update() {
        var dir = Math.PI * this.direction / 180;
        this.y += Math.sin(dir) * this.speed;       
        this.x += Math.cos(dir) * this.speed;
        this.fillStyle();
    }

    draw(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        this.fillStyle();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();
    }

    setup() {
        this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        this.speed = Math.random() * 1.5;
        this.direction = Math.random() * 360;
        this.radius = Math.random() * (canvas.width / canvas.height)*0.15; 
    }
}

function drawdotLines(net) {
    var copyNet = net.slice();
    while (copyNet.length > 0) {
        var dot = copyNet.pop();
        for (var n = 0; n < copyNet.length; n++) {
            var ndot = copyNet[n];
            var rx = Math.pow(dot.x - ndot.x, 2);
            var ry = Math.pow(dot.y - ndot.y, 2);
            var dist = Math.sqrt(rx + ry);
            if (dist < weight) {
                context.beginPath();
                index = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('index'));
                if (dot.x > 4 * (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
                    context.strokeStyle = fifth[index];
                } else if (dot.x > 3 * (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
                    context.strokeStyle = fourth[index];
                } else if (dot.x > 2 * (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
                    context.strokeStyle = third[index];
                } else if (dot.x > (context.canvas.width) / 5) {
                    context.strokeStyle = second[index];
                } else {
                    context.strokeStyle = first[index];
                }
                context.lineWidth = 2 * (weight - dist) / weight;
                context.moveTo(dot.x, dot.y);
                context.lineTo(ndot.x, ndot.y);
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}

function update() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < net.length; i++) {
        var dot = net[i];
        dot.update();
        dot.draw(context);
        if (dot.x < 0 || dot.x > canvas.width || dot.y < 0 || dot.y > canvas.height) {
            dot.setup();
        }
    }
    drawdotLines(net);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("color_change").onclick = function () {
    if (index == first.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
        toString(index);
        localStorage.setItem('index', index);
        update();
    } else {
        index++;
        localStorage.setItem('index', index);
        update();
    }
}
```

And this is how I tried to create my canvas, this is at the bottom of my script file, I've already tried the solution given in the link above but it didn't works at all.

```
for(var j=1;j<=nbCanvas;j++){
    let nd_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas#dot_"+j);
    window.setInterval(update.bind(this,canvas), 15); 
}
```

What I expect is something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/LIghningWolf/ygq2srj0/1 
I've made this fiddle to show the result but I want it for as many canvas I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal intrusion is probably to copy your canvas pixels to your destination canvas.

Since the `update` draws your canvas, we can assume that after each updates, the canvas is to be copied:

```
    drawdotLines(net);
        [...document.querySelectorAll('.copy')].forEach(dst=>{
            dst.getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
            dst.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)
    })
```

Just modify the css to check the `copy`-canvas are indeed correctly "replicated"

```
canvas{
...
    width:30%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

and do not forget to add the canvas to the dom

```
       <canvas id="dot1"></canvas>
       <canvas class="copy"></canvas>
       <canvas class="copy"></canvas>
```

As a side node, every time you `update`, you query the DOM to get access to your destination canvas. Better pass the contexts as argument to `update` instead.

edit: your fiddle modified http://jsfiddle.net/ndq6fa38/

edit2: you may want to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval`

---

As LightninWolf precised, the goal is to have separate buttons.
Then this is just about refactoring/encapsulating.
Wrap all the drawing code inside a function and pass it a `canvas`

```
function makeButton(canvas){
...

  function update() {...

  }
    return {update}
}
```

Make some buttons

```
let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
let btns = [...canvas].map(canvas=>{
        return makeButton(canvas);
})
btns.forEach(btn=>{
    window.setInterval(btn.update.bind(btn), 15); 
})
```

The buttons are now independant.

NB: the same could be applied for the `a` onclick event.
As the `a` is bound to one `canvas`, consider `makeButton(canvas, a)` and handle the click per `btn` instance

edit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpn0wu4m/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and complete answer, this is almost what I wanted to do. My problem for me is that I don't really want to copy the first canvas, my anchor tag act as a button and I want the canva to fit my canvas, each anchor would have his very own canvas so when I hover it the animation starts for the button I'm hovering. Still a great answer for me I guess I can try something from what you gave to me !

Comment: @LightninWolf silly mind I have, didn't even occur to me that you wanted different buttons. See second part of my edit post

Comment: Well what can I say except your are my hero, this is exactly what I wanted. The "encapsulation" trick was part of the answer in the link in my original post but whatever I tried I couldn't set it up as needed, but you did it so easily. Thanks a lot for your help.